# Howto structure my app.js code to make it easier testable

Tags: testing, tdd, node.js, integration-tests, acceptance-testing

I have a couple of Philip Hue lights in the hallway. These show the build status on their lights with a small Node.JS application. Its working like a charm.

Currently I am in the process of testing and refactoring this application, but in my `app.js` I have some lines of code where I am having a hard time to figure out how to automatically test them.

```js
if(config.enabledHueUpdateJobs) {
    var Hue = require('./hue.js');
    var Lights = require('./lights.js');

    var hallwayLights = new Lights(new Hue());
    hallwayLights.scheduleOn('45 7 * * 1-5');
    hallwayLights.scheduleOff('30 17 * * 1-5');    
    hallwayLights.scheduleUpdate('*/30 * 7-18 * * 1-5', buildServer.getFailedBuildCount);
}
```

I have 100% coverage for the `Hue.js` and the `Lights.js` 'classes', but the actual implementation code is not covered. I have had an issue where I changed the 'classes' public methods, but not the implementation code, but this was not caught by my tests.

I have been thinking about moving this code to a 'class' with a `.start()` function, but then still I would have one or two untested lines.

Please suggest a way how I can restructure my code (or some best practices/patterns that I should research/use) to make this better testable.

**Update**:

- I want to let our build-server deploy a working version after all my tests have run. So I don't have to check the system manually.
- I would like to have a TDD workflow, I would like to stay in my IDE and be confident to push my final changes.
- Preferably I do not want to start 'node app.js' and test it with some blackbox testing system

Comment: Um, how do you actually get feedback from a Phillip Hue light to prove that your tests work?  Are you using some sort of calibrated color sensor?

Comment: In addition, what value do such tests bring to the table that a visual inspection of the output of the bulb doesn't already provide?

Comment: I don't really think I need feedback from the lights, I am already mocking the API. Also I do not want to test the lamps have the right color, I trust the Hue API to work and be wel tested itself.

Comment: I just want to make sure when I am adding a new feature TDD style or when refactoring that I don't forget to update the code in app.js. For example I could rename the Lights class to HallwayLamps, because I think it reads better, all my tests would succeed on the build-server and the build-server will auto deploy to the production system. But if I forgot to update the app.js the system is broken. I just want to cover the actual implementation with tests so I can safely update the system without manual testing it.

Comment: How many different states does this system have?  Build succeeded, build failed, build partially succeeded?  Seems to me like you need 3 integration tests, and you're done.

Comment: It has 5 states, but those are covered by tests for the Lights.js. I guess the question is how do I write an integration tests that starts app.js and runs my code to check it works. That is easy for a module/class object, but not so straight forward for the actual application. Preferably I do not want to start 'node app.js' and test it with some blackbox testing system. I figure there are alternative ways to test this code by structuring it differently.

Comment: Problem is that the app test would test only the bootstraping. Isn't? But those lines that require user actions would remain untested. I guess that app.js is totally opaque. A big *static void method*. A possible way could be implementing app events that could be tracked and asserted by the test enginee. It might interest you also to provide the app.js with a public and parametrized interface in order to test configurations that help you to force executions to step into conditionals like the exposed one.

Comment: The idea around testing via event tracking is that the abscence of an expected event causes a test KO.. Unexpected data provided by the event also causes KO. Or exceeded timeouts (I looking at these schedules of the Light.js).

Comment: RobertHarvey, thanks for calling it an integration test. Laiv, thanks for your ideas. I think parameterizing the interface helped to push me into my current solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution to write an integration-test for my code. I will try to explain my implementation.

I have added a way to start and stop my code in app.js. (I was already using a similar strategy for my Selenium tests for another project) This way I can start and stop the app.js code from the tests, without starting `'node app.js'` from the command-line.

app.js code:

```
exports.start = function () {
    buildServer.updateCaches();

    var hallwayLights = new Lights(new Hue(config.hueServerUrl, config.hueUserName));
    jobs.push(hallwayLights.scheduleOn(config.lightsOnSchedule));
    jobs.push(hallwayLights.scheduleOff(config.lightsOffSchedule));    
    jobs.push(hallwayLights.scheduleUpdate(config.lightsUpdateSchedule, buildServer.getFailedBuildCount)); 
}

exports.close = function() {
    jobs.forEach(function (job) {
        job.cancel();
    }); 
}

if (!isStartedFromTests()) { exports.start(); }
function isStartedFromTests() { return module.id != require.main.id; }
```

In the tests (using [ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava)) I [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) all the expected external API calls and verify they have been called.

test.integration.js code:

```js
test.cb('Radiator: Should execute light schedules When the app is started', t => {
    // Arrange
    t.plan(3);
    var bsNocks = new buildServerNocks(config.buildserverServerName, config.buildserverPort);
    bsNocks.buildSuccess('Project1_Build1');
    bsNocks.buildSuccess('Project1_Build2');
    bsNocks.buildFailed('Project2_SubProject_Build3');

    var light1 = nock(config.hueServerUrl + config.hueUserName).put('/lights/1/state', hue.colors['red']).reply(200);
    var light2 = nock(config.hueServerUrl + config.hueUserName).put('/lights/2/state', hue.colors['green']).reply(200);
    var light3 = nock(config.hueServerUrl + config.hueUserName).put('/lights/3/state', hue.colors['green']).reply(200);

    // Act
    app.start();

    // Assert
    setTimeout(function() {
        t.is(light1.done())
        t.is(light2.done())
        t.is(light3.done())
        app.close();        
        t.end();
    }, 1200);
});
```

In the development.js config file I set the cron-schedule to every second, so it tests very fast. I moved the actual configs to production.js. This configuration setup is described in [this blog post](http://eng.datafox.co/nodejs/2014/09/28/nodejs-config-best-practices/).

```js
lightsUpdateSchedule: '*/1 * * * * *'
```

I have verified it works as expected by changing some internal function names like `scheduleOn` to `jobOn` and see that the test does fail.

Although it works, I am not yet convinced this is the best and most readable solution. Still open for other answers or idea's.